# How to permit only admin can update role column in user table with cancancan?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancancan

I want to let admin can set other user to admin/manager by edit role column in database. I try to use cancancan gem to do this but nothing happen.

How can I do this?

ability.rb

```
def initialize(user)
  user ||= User.new 
  if user.admin?
    can [:create, :update, :destroy], [Organization, Club, User]
  elsif user.manager?
    can [:create, :update, :destroy], [User, Event, News, User_club, User_event]
    can :update, Club
    can :read, :all
    cannot :update, user.role
  else
    can :read, :all
    can :create, User
    can :update, User, user_id: user.id
    cannot :update, user.role
  end
end
```

edit.html.erb

```
<% if can? :update, @user.role %>
   <%= f.label :role %>
   <%= f.number_field :role, class: "form-control" %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You try [this](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/Cancancan)

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability
  def initialize(user)
    can :read, :all                   # allow everyone to read everything
    if user && user.admin?
      can :access, :rails_admin       # only allow admin users to access Rails Admin
      can :dashboard                  # allow access to dashboard
      if user.role? :superadmin
        can :manage, :all             # allow superadmins to do anything
      elsif user.role? :manager
        can :manage, [User, Product]  # allow managers to do anything to products and users
      elsif user.role? :sales
        can :update, Product, :hidden => false  # allow sales to only update visible products
      end
    end
  end
end
```